# Displaying error messages from Controller in View

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have seen a lot of people say that using `Viewdata` or `ViewBag` is not a good practice for this matter(displaying messages from the controller) because of security reasons. Everyone seems to suggest `ModelState`
My question is what is wrong with using viewdata to display error messages? If we arent supposed to use `ViewData` then what should we use it for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC 5 ViewBag security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976615/mvc-5-viewbag-security)

Answer (score 0):

As @shenku answered before, `ViewData` and `ModelState` reference the exact same thing, if you look at the code for `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class you will see the implementation for ModelState is:

```
   public ModelStateDictionary ModelState
    {
      get
      {
        return this.ViewData.ModelState;
      }
    }
```

and @JimmiTh said,
although the main use of `ModelState` from an "end developer"'s perspective is in the controller, `ViewData` is used as a container for all data that's communicated between the controller and the view. Which is why it also needs to include `ModelState` - because, although you'd rarely use it directly in the view, `ModelState` is where e.g. many of the `HtmlHelper` methods actually get the values from by default when rendering the view from a POST action - rather than Model.